# React-Admin, Empty the ArrayInput according to ReferenceInput

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a code as follows (I'm using react-admin on the frontend);

```
<ReferenceInput label="DataPoint Types" source="datapointtype" reference="datapointtypes" onChange={this.dptChanged}>
    <SelectInput optionText="id" />
</ReferenceInput>
<ArrayInput source='parameters'>
    <SimpleFormIterator>
        <TextInput source='id' label="name" validate {this.validateParameterName} />
        <ReferenceInput label="Parameter DataType" source="parameters" reference="datatypes">
            <SelectInput optionText="id" source="id" />
        </ReferenceInput>
    </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

Change function;

```
dptChanged(event) {
    const dataPointType = Object.values(event).slice(0, -1).join('');
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/designer/datapointtypes/' + dataPointType)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data.parameters) {
                this.setState({
                    connectedParameters: Object.values(response.data.parameters)
                })
            }
        });

    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/designer/datatypes')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                datatypes: response.data
            })
        })
}
```

The thing that I want to do is like that; when I change the SelectInput (datapointtype), the "parameters" ArrayInput must be empty, even if it has elements.

How can I do that?

Comment: can you please show SelectInput change function?

Comment: Content of change function is about another requirement for now. I mean there is nothing for my problem in the function. But I've added it for you

Comment: hey @CanselMuti, wanted to ask whether each ReferenceInput calls your API? So if you have 10 of them on page, you have 10 additional requests?

Comment: Hey @mmmm. That was true so there were 10 additional requests but of course, we've changed this process. I don't remember exactly but probably we have used redux to do that without 10 additional requests

Comment: so it wasn't in react-admin out of the box?

Comment: Sort of... In fact, we had a lot of difficulties about ArrayInput component in react-admin for our project and complicated use cases. So, we decided not to use the react-admin. We started to use pure material-ui components after that I asked this question